# Merge Surface Fill into Solid Fusion 360 (or otherwise fill pocket)

Tags: autodesk-fusion-360

I am designing an enclosure with various filleted edges. I am trying to create a something like a fillet at the corner here:

[image]

I can easily create a surface fill, but I can't figure out how to join this new surface into a unified solid:

[image]

What is the best way that I can join this surface into a unified solid, or otherwise fill this pocket area in the way I've described?

Comment: 3D CAD software isn't within the scope of graphic design.  Perhaps try Engineering Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Billy Kerr but the forum has a fusion 360 tag 

Comment: @emmett anybody can create a tag. Anybody can misuse the place. Stackexhange isnt really a forum. It is also possible that the question is graphic design although this isnt it. And did you read the tag description: "This is a CAD application, make sure your question relates to graphic design. General questions on how to use are likely to be off topic. "

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that eventually you will want to manufacture stuff. And since cad applications are manufacturing agnostic sooner or later we are talking about finer points of structuring your history, manufacturing limitations, engineering philosophy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extrude the surface to its normal direction at the convex side. Combine the generated solid to the original one.

**Warning:** Making solids by extruding curved surfaces has a special function in Fusion 360. There it's  Surface > Create > Thicken. "Extrude" accepts only planar surfaces in F360.

[image]

This image is after making the extrusion but before combining the solid bodies to one. The transparent blue solid is the original. The extruded patch fill surface is red.

ADDED: User joojaa suggest in his comment other methods which may create internally simpler result. I tested one of them and it worked. I removed the 3 unnecessary planar faces of the corner, made the patch fill surface and stitched together all surfaces. The resulted solid body looks the same as the first version, but it has never had as many geometric features.

[image]

Comment: I can't figure out to select the surface that's created for extrusion, do you know how that is done?

Comment: @emmett Extrusion is a bad name for the operation. The right term in F360 is "Thicken". It is behind Create > Surface. Sorry for making a mixture between different programs. Extrusion is for planar surfaces.

Comment: One should probably be using boundary fill or stitch for a better history management. Not much point in making things more fragile than needed

Comment: @joojaa I inserted it to the answer. Thanks for the notification.